# Javascript merge nested array with same object names?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array object 
[image]

Here is the array

```
tagGroups: Array(6)
[
{name: "Function", tags: Array(1)}
{name: "Function", tags: Array(1)}
{name: "Function", tags: Array(1)}
{name: "Test", tags: Array(1)}
{name: "Test", tags: Array(1)}
{name: "new", tags: Array(1)}
]
```

I need to be able to merge the tags array with the same name of object so I would end up with the following

```
{
            "name": "Tag Group 1",
            "tags": [
                "TagA",
                "TagB",
                "TagC"
            ]
        },
```

This is my correct code, which creates the object format

```
// Creates the final format that can be upload or stored
        for (var i = 0, l = tagGroupsArr.length; i < l; i++) {
            tagGroupsTemp = {name: tagGroupsArr[i].tagGroupName, tags: [tagGroupsArr[i].tag]};
            tagGroupsFinal.push(tagGroupsTemp);
        }
```

Comment: can we expect the array instead of the snapshot?

Comment: Can you clarify? Is "Tag A", "Tag B", "Tag C" on your example means "Function", "Test" and "new"?

Comment: *This is my correct code, which creates the object format*. And?

Comment: Added the array, it creates the objects but it should be one object for the same name so I would have {name: "Function", tags: Array(3)}

and Test would be like so {name: "Test", tags: Array(2)}

i.e. find the same name create only one object with that name and push all the tags into that one object

Comment: Please update the question with input array and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to create a new object with name of object as key and the object as its value. Then, you can `concat` the `tags` array if its `name` is already present in the new object. After that, you can use `Object.values()` to get the merged tags object.

```js
const tagGroupes = [{name: "Function", tags: ["TagA"]},{name: "Function", tags: ["TagB"]},{name: "Function", tags: ["TagC"]},{name: "Test", tags: ["TestA"]},{name: "Test", tags: ["TestB"]},{name: "new", tags: ["newA"]}]

const result = tagGroupes.reduce((res, obj) => {
  if(res[obj.name]){
    res[obj.name].tags = res[obj.name].tags.concat(obj.tags);
  } else {
    res[obj.name] = obj;
  }
  return res;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```