# Javascript multiple group by for dynamic field

Tags: javascript

```
    [ 
        { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "4" },
        { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "3", Value2: "7" },
        { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "2" },
        { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "2", Value2: "1" },
        { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "3" },
        { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "4", Value2: "8" },
        { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "5", Value2: "1" },
        { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "1" }
    ]
```

Hi, i have a this Array of objects and i am expecting the below format. 
I wants to get result by adding all data for value1, value2 (It can be dynamic or may be more)
Grouping by Phase.

I am coding in javascript but, result is not coming proper.

```
    [ 
        { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "15", Value2: "14" },
        { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "11", Value2: "13" }
    ]
```

I can't find any way to achive this.

```
    function utils(data, field){
        var data = [{ Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "4" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "3", Value2: "7" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "2" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "2", Value2: "1" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "1", Value2: "3" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "4", Value2: "8" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "5", Value2: "1" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "1", Value2: "1" }],
        result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { Phase, ...o }) => {
            if (!r[Phase]) r[Phase] = { Phase };
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[Phase][k] = (r[Phase][k] || 0) + +v);
            return r;
        }, {}));

        return result
    }


    utils(data, "Phase")
```

Here i have written code like this. but, the **field** should be **dynamic** here if i change 
the **field** **Phase** to something else is is coming **undefined** and not coming result incorrect.

I wants to use **field** what i am sending in function instead of **Phase**. That has to be dynamic

Please have a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript merge nested array with same object names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194275/javascript-merge-nested-array-with-same-object-names)

Comment: That output is different. Mine is differentr

Comment: its all the same, your just iterating through nested arrays for common values, then joining into new simple array. Some of the answers in that link solve Exactly that with clear step by descriptions on how and why. Step back a little and see it as that, your just changing one little step in a very very very commonly posted question, with literally dozens of helpful posts on SO and elsewhere already

Comment: i want help in my code. it is working but want Phase to dynamic

Answer (score 1):

this solution might work for you

```js
var arr = [
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "4" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "3", Value2: "7" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "2" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "2", Value2: "1" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2",  Value1: "1", Value2: "3" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "4", Value2: "8" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "5", Value2: "1" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "1", Value2: "1" }
];

var outPut = arr.reduce((a, b) => {

  //check result array has the phase
  let c = a.find(e => e.Phase == b.Phase);
  
  //if result array has the phase, increase properties values
  if (c) {
    c.Value1 = String(parseInt(c.Value1) + parseInt(b.Value1));
    c.Value2 = String(parseInt(c.Value2) + parseInt(b.Value2));
  } 
  //if not add current object into result array
  else
    a.push(b);

  return a;

}, []);

console.log(outPut);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and accumulate based on `Phase`.

```js
const data = [ { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "4" }, { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "3", Value2: "7" }, { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "2" }, { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "2", Value2: "1" }, { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "3" }, { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "4", Value2: "8" }, { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "5", Value2: "1" }, { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "1" } ],
      result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.Phase] = r[o.Phase] || {Phase: o.Phase, Value1: 0, Value2: 0};
        r[o.Phase].Value1 += +o.Value1;
        r[o.Phase].Value2 += +o.Value2;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```